# Как сделать конкруктор форм через админку Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Я хочу, чтобы в админке мог менять нужные мне поля. Например, анкета, сегодня там одни поля: ФИО, возраст, номер телефона, а завтра я захочу поменять на: ФИО, Номер телефона, почту, не залезая в код, а прямо из админки. Есть ли уже какие-то статьи на эту тему или ответы тех, кто столкнулся с той же проблемой, как такое реализовать на Django?

Статьи/ответы на русском/англ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ [тут](https://github.com/raison-collab/DjangoFormConstructor). Если вдруг у кого будут вопросы, как это работает, то форма открывается по `forms/<int:form_id>` (это прописано в файле `urls.py`) `form_id` это id записи формы в БД